# How to get an attachment from specified path

Tags: java

I just have a path given from the database. it supposed an attachemenet saved on that path. how can i get this attachment using java?

Comment: That depends where the attachment is stored.

Comment: What is your question man? Please edit it to make it more clear..

Comment: Are you talking about a file path or a URI?

Comment: Show what kind of "path", one example will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to give us more information so that we can help you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: for example if i get the path from the database like : D:\\Projects\\image.jpg , how can i get the attachment from this given path?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is applicable when you want to read attachment from your local,
If you want to read file from remote system or some other things there are different ways.

```
      String filePAthDB ="E:/Eclipse-Leo/RD_JMS/src/test/textfile.jpg";
      File f = new File(filePAthDB );
      if(f.exists())
       {
            //process file whatever you want
          System.out.println("Attachment available......");
       }
      else
          System.out.println("not Attachment available......");
```